# Algorithm for calculating real, positive roots of transcendental equation involving tangens

Tags: transcendental-equations

Crank ("The mathematics of diffusion", 2nd editon, 1975, p.57) describes a diffusion modelling algorithm which relies on the non-zero positive roots of

$$ \tan{q_n} = -\alpha\cdot q_n$$

Typical values I use for $\alpha : 0.1, 1, 10, 15, 25, 50,... $

To achieve the necessary accuracy for small diffusion coefficients (e. g. $10^{-16} $) I need to calculate several hundred roots. I currently use Mathematica to calculate the roots, but this is a quite painful procedure. Therefore I would like to write a C++ program which will help me calculating the roots. For that I would need an algorithm to solve above equation. Any help with that would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. MathJax supports backslashes for many purposes; e.g., $\tan$ should be rendered with `\tan`

Comment: Based on some experimentation, for reasonably small values of $\alpha$, you can let $f(x)=\tan(x)+\alpha x$ and pick an initial guess of $x_0=2$ for Newton's method. Repeat the process as many times as needed, and then use $x_0=2+\pi$ for your next initial guess and find the next root. Then use $2+2\pi$ as your initial guess, then $2+3\pi$, etc.

Comment: @K.defaoite: Thanks - very helpful :-)

Comment: There were a few mistakes. Sorry for that. Cheers :-)

Comment: I suppose that with $\alpha=0.1$ it will not be very good. Try and let me know.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici:I compared your analytical values with numerical values calculated with Mathematica. For α=0.1 there are considerable differences for n=0 to 2. For n = 3 the difference is 4.9%. For n = 4 difference decreased to 0.07%. Difference is decreasing further with higher values of n. For α=1 n = 0 is completely off. n = 1 is very close to the numerical value (8.26e-7%). From n = 3 analytical and numerical values are identically (resolution: 13 digits behind decimal point).

Comment: @whoever. All of that is normal. What you can do (in order to polish the root) is one iteration of Newton or Halley methods starting with the given estimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the zero's of function
$$f(x)=\tan(x)+\alpha x$$ They will be closer and closer to $(2n+1)\frac \pi 2$. To remove the unpleasant discontinuities, consider instead
$$g(x)=\sin(x)+\alpha x \cos(x)$$ and use Taylor series around $x=(2n+1)\frac \pi 2$
$$g(x)=\frac 12\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{ 2 (\alpha  k+1) \cos \left(\frac{\pi  k}{2}\right)-\pi  \alpha 
   (2 n+1) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  k}{2}\right)}{ k!}\Big[x-  (2 n+1)\frac \pi 2\Big]^k$$ Truncate to some order and use series reversion to obtain fot the $n^{\text{th}}$ root
$$x_{(n)}= t+\sum_{m=0}^p (-1)^{m}\frac {c_m} {(\alpha t)^{2m+1}}\qquad \text{where} \qquad t=(2n+1)\frac \pi 2$$

The first coefficients $c_m$ are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
m & c_m \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & \alpha +\frac{1}{3} \\
 2 & 2 \alpha ^2+\frac{4 \alpha }{3}+\frac{1}{5} \\
 3 & 5 \alpha ^3+5 \alpha ^2+\frac{23 \alpha }{15}+\frac{1}{7} \\
 4 & 14 \alpha ^4+\frac{56 \alpha ^3}{3}+\frac{392 \alpha ^2}{45}+\frac{176 \alpha
   }{105}+\frac{1}{9} \\
 5 & 42 \alpha ^5+70 \alpha ^4+44 \alpha ^3+\frac{818 \alpha ^2}{63}+\frac{563
   \alpha }{315}+\frac{1}{11} \\
 6 & 132 \alpha ^6+264 \alpha ^5+209 \alpha ^4+\frac{15796 \alpha
   ^3}{189}+\frac{3102 \alpha ^2}{175}+\frac{6508 \alpha }{3465}+\frac{61}{1024} \\
 7 & 429 \alpha ^7+1001 \alpha ^6+\frac{43043 \alpha ^5}{45}+\frac{65351 \alpha
   ^4}{135}+\frac{282841 \alpha ^3}{2025}+\frac{1534247 \alpha
   ^2}{57600}+\frac{141583 \alpha }{23040}+\frac{18811}{15360}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Trying for $\alpha=10$ with $p=7$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 &\color{red}{1.63199452}646140205048274685183 &  
                1.63199452721480006371688983888 \\
 1 & \color{red}{4.733511802356786}19428997112737 & 
                 4.73351180235678620084907851480 \\
 2 & \color{red}{7.86669277156157419748}480845369 & 
                 7.86669277156157419748592987705 \\
 3 & \color{red}{11.004661096033518512264}5971500 & 
                 11.0046610960335185122646008382 \\
 4 & \color{red}{14.1442368407184333320452158}130 &
                 14.1442368407184333320452158645 \\
 5 & \color{red}{17.28454504550461827956001048}46 & 
                 17.2845450455046182795600104863 \\
 6 & \color{red}{20.425248110576069042708349747}2 & 
                 20.4252481105760690427083497473 \\
 7 & \color{red}{23.5661882440696287891706461263} & 
                 23.5661882440696287891706461263 
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

If you are not looking for too much accuracy, rewrite

$$x_{(n)}= t+\sum_{m=0}^p (-1)^{m}\frac {c_m} {(\alpha t)^{2m+1}}=t+\frac 1 {\alpha t}\sum_{m=0}^p (-1)^{m} c_m \,y^m$$ with $y=\frac  1{(\alpha t)^2} $ and use the simplest Padé approximant
$$\sum_{m=0}^p (-1)^{m} c_m \,y^m=\frac{c_0 c_1+\left(c_0 c_2-c_1^2\right) y } {c_1+c_2y }+O\left(y^3\right)$$

For $\alpha=10$ as above, the solutions will be
$$\{1.631998,4.733512,7.866693,11.00466,14.14424,17.28455,20.42525,23.56619\}$$

Comment: Very nice indeed.

Comment: First of all many thanks for the really nice derivation. You refined & expanded your answer compared with yesterday. I calculated some values with your equation yesterday (1.6320227505878306, 4.73351184288659, 7.866692774190552,...) which I think are consistent with the results you calculated. Today I tried to calculate some results for alpha = 10 and p = 3, but I came to results which are quite off. If I compare the equations from today with the equations you posted yesterday they do not seem to be identically.

Comment: @whoever. I shall rework and post.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Many thanks for the update of your posting. The calculations now seem all to be ok and a nice touch to color the digits to show that the solution is getting closer and closer to the approximation. In order to make your answer more readable for other viewers I have two very small formal suggestions: you could again mention case c0 = 1 because it is part of the summation. The summation variable n could be replaced with some other variable, because it is not the n of x(n) and not the n mentioned in the equation for t (t could be labelled with n in the summation).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: yes the answer is perfect now. Many thanks for your help with it. I just accepted it. :-)